# Search in a file for Specific sentences in a txt file in java

Tags: java, file

I have a TXT file with a multiple choice question and answer(like 150 question),this is the format:

1. what's your name?
   a. danny
   b. pedro
   c. jose
   d. mikey

I need to seek in the file and get the questions and the answer to show them in a UI interface.

For the moment, I can read and print the file, but I don't know how to get the sentence for separate.
Any suggestion?

The code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class fileManager {

public FileInputStream inputStream;
public InputStreamReader reader;
public File myfile;
public String question;
public String [] answer;


public fileManager(String myfile) {
    this.myfile = new File(String.valueOf(myfile));
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(this.myfile );
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream , "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void printFile(){
    int indexChar = 1;
    char concatination = '.';
    int endFile = 0;
    try {
        endFile = inputStream.available();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    do {
        try {
            char mychar = (char)reader.read();
            if (mychar == ((char)indexChar)){
                if(concatination == (char)reader.read()){
                    do{
                        System.out.print((char)reader.read());
                    }while ((char)reader.read() == 'א');
                }
            }
            endFile++;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }while(endFile < 1000);
}

public void closeFile(){
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} //End function

public void getChar(){


}


public void getTheQuestion(){
    int questionNum = 0;
    int eof = 0;
    int i =0;
    String []file;
    String question;

    try {
        eof = inputStream.available();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (;i == '1';){

        try {
            i = reader.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}//end  getTheQuestion


//Getters and Setters
public FileInputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}

public void setInputStream(FileInputStream inputStream) {
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
}

public File getMyfile() {
    return myfile;
}

public void setMyfile(File myfile) {
    this.myfile = myfile;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String[] getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public void setAnswer(String[] answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}

}
```

Comment: First suggestion: Share your code with us, so we have something to look at. Second suggestion: Have a look at splitting strings using regex, once you have read in the TXT file.

Comment: The code I have is Irrelevant, and the second suggestion I'm checking.

Comment: Oh, code is never irrelevant, Particularly not when asking about help here at SO.

Comment: I think my question is a General one, is more like how should be performed certain task.

Comment: Sure, maybe not all code is relevant, but at least the part you at least have questions about. Please update me/us on how it goes, if you solved it by splitting the resulting strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it with regular expressions. Here I have written a program to help.
I have created `Pattern`'s for questions and all four options and then fetched them.

```
File file = new File("myfile.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
Pattern questionPattern = Pattern.compile("(^(.+\\?)(?=(\\s+(a\\.\\s+.+)"
        + "\\s+b\\.\\s+.+\\s+c\\.\\s+.+\\s+d\\.\\s+.+)))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Pattern optionAPattern = Pattern.compile("((?<=(.+\\?\\s))(a\\..+)(?=(\\sb\\..+$)))");
Pattern optionBPattern = Pattern.compile("((?<=(\\s))(b\\..+)(?=(\\sc\\..+$)))");
Pattern optionCPattern = Pattern.compile("((?<=(\\s))(c\\..+)(?=(\\sd\\..+$)))");
Pattern optionDPattern = Pattern.compile("((?<=(\\s))(d\\..+)(?=(\\s*$)))");

if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    Matcher question = questionPattern.matcher(line);
    Matcher optionA = optionAPattern.matcher(line);
    Matcher optionB = optionBPattern.matcher(line);
    Matcher optionC = optionCPattern.matcher(line);
    Matcher optionD = optionDPattern.matcher(line);

    if(question.find()) System.out.println(question.group());
    if(optionA.find())  System.out.println(optionA.group());
    if(optionB.find())  System.out.println(optionB.group());
    if(optionC.find())  System.out.println(optionC.group());
    if(optionD.find())  System.out.println(optionD.group());
}
```

**Output :**

```
what's your name?
a. danny
b. pedro
c. jose
d. mikey
```

*I think you are a beginner. Try learning regular expression to understand the code*

Answer (score 1):

I use the afzalex solution,
Scanner look at line, so I suppose my line start with the "index Letters"(Actually is in hebrew)so I understand its an answer, you can look at createPatterns(), and the question is not the answer so i left them, and  I decide  this will be in the end of the IF sentences, Where if is not empty enter to add question.

Here the code:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.Match;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    /**
     * Created by aby on 11/9/14.
     */
    public class fileManager {

        public File myfile;
        public Pattern myAnswerAlef;
        public Pattern myAnswerBet;
        public Pattern myAnswerGimel;
        public Pattern myAnswerDalet;
        public Scanner myscanner;
        List<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> answerAlef = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> answerBet = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> answerGimel = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> answerDalet = new ArrayList<String>();


        public fileManager(String myfile) {
            this.myfile = new File(String.valueOf(myfile));
            try {
                myscanner = new Scanner(this.myfile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            getAnswerQuestions();
        }

        public void closeFile(){
            myscanner.close();
        } //End function

        public void createPatterns(){
            myAnswerAlef  = Pattern.compile("[א]+[.]");
            myAnswerBet   = Pattern.compile("[ב]+[.]");
            myAnswerGimel = Pattern.compile("[ג]+[.]");
            myAnswerDalet = Pattern.compile("[ד]+[.]");
        }

        public void getAnswerQuestions(){

            createPatterns();
            do {
                String line = myscanner.nextLine();

                if(line.length() != 1){
                    Matcher MatcherAnswerAlef = myAnswerAlef.matcher(line);
                    Matcher MatcherAnswerBet = myAnswerBet.matcher(line);
                    Matcher MatcherAnswerGimel = myAnswerGimel.matcher(line);
                    Matcher MatcherAnswerDalet = myAnswerDalet.matcher(line);

                    if (MatcherAnswerAlef.find()){
                        answerAlef.add(line);
                    }
                    else
                    if (MatcherAnswerBet.find()){
                        answerBet.add(line);
                    }
                    else
                    if (MatcherAnswerGimel.find()){
                       answerGimel.add(line);
                    }
                    else
                    if (MatcherAnswerDalet.find()){
                        answerDalet.add(line);
                    }
                    else
                    if (!line.isEmpty()){
                          question.add(line);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }while (myscanner.hasNext());

        }



    }
```